How to make the most of a low-ranked undergrad?
I am currently a senior in high school. By the time I start college, I will have taken several dual enrollment classes (specifically Discrete Math, Real Analysis 1/2, DiffEq, LinAlg, Stats 1/2, and Probability). My credits transfer over, so I will be able to complete my major-specific requirements after 2 semesters.
I will likely go to a nearby school for undergrad - not a bad school per se, but not a T50 either. I’ve heard that attending a school outside of the T50 vastly decreases one’s chances of getting into a good graduate school. How true is this, and how can I compensate for it?
I'm also not entirely sure if I want to go to graduate school - I suppose it's too early to say at 16. If I choose to get a job in the 'industry,' will employers look down on me for having gone to a random school? If so, how can I compensate for this?
Thank you all for your help. Please tell me if this is the correct place to post this question or if there is a career-advice specific forum that I can post to.

This is off-topic here and probably also on Academia.SE. But for context - my math program in undergrad was only about 8 years old and only admitted juniors and seniors, and I was able to get into one of the top grad programs in Texas. Ranking doesn't ultimately matter.

^ Strong letters of recommendation and research experience can easily make up for a lower ranking. I did vote to close because this question is off topic. Good luck though!
